# Is there a Rollcall of users with their number of "accepted answers"?

Tags: feature-request

There are many other "rollcalls" of users listing the numbers of their Reviews, Edits, etc. But I fail to find one listing users with the most number of "Accepted Answers."

Would this be a listing of enough interest to program one on Biblical Hermeneutics SE? It would reveal, not just the amount of Reputation a user has (as is already shown), but the type of Answers the Askers want. (Not, of course, thinking that the Answers are always infallibly inspired or correct).

{For a while, there was a "Top Ten" for the Christianity site, that was listed on Meta.Stackexchange, but was cancelled.}

Comment: Except that having an accepted answer doesn't indicate that the answer was the highest quality. It could've been the first answer, or the simplest answer, or the answer that most agreed with the question asker's preconceptions, or anything else.

Comment: @ curiousdannii - Trueness! In fact, we can't even be sure of any of the Answers without confirming them with our own research to back them up. **Although** the Answer do often direct us to other important resources, or expand our minds to think of other possible Answers we hadn't thought of before. So SE is quite profitable and a blessing.

Comment: Probably the tag ([meta-tag:accepted-answer]) would be suitable here.

Comment: Here is a SEDE query I created a long time ago: [main](https://data.stackexchange.com/hermeneutics/query/1433233/users-with-highest-number-of-accepted-answers), [meta](https://data.stackexchange.com/meta.hermeneutics/query/1433233/users-with-highest-number-of-accepted-answers).

Comment: @ Martin Sleziak - Fantastic! Good programming! Just what the doctor ordered. The "tag" grouped the pertinent questions magnificently.  (A tag I didn't know existed.)  Thank you for responding with your comments!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Stack Exchange Data Exporer (SEDE)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/data-explorer/info) is a suitable tool which can be used to get various stats. (Some knowledge of SQL is needed, but there is a tutorial and you can find many existing queries in various discussions.)
The description of available tables can be found here: [Database schema documentation for the public data dump and SEDE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/2677).
The database in SEDE is updated once a week - so the stats won't be completely up-to-date.

Some stats which might be interesting in connection with accepted answer:

- About answerers: how many of their answer are accepted: [main](https://data.stackexchange.com/hermeneutics/query/1821176/answers-number-and-percentage-of-accepted-answers), [meta](https://data.stackexchange.com/meta.hermeneutics/query/1821176/answers-number-and-percentage-of-accepted-answers).
- About askers: how many of their questions get an accepted answer: [main](https://data.stackexchange.com/hermeneutics/query/1821177/questions-number-and-percentage-of-accepted-answers), [meta](https://data.stackexchange.com/meta.hermeneutics/query/1821177/questions-number-and-percentage-of-accepted-answers)
- If we want to measure how many questions get answers, here are some stats about questions that have at least one answer and questions that have an accepted answer. Here are the [total numbers](https://data.stackexchange.com/hermeneutics/query/1813993/number-of-questions-with-at-least-one-answer-an-accepted-answer-per-month#graph) and [percentages](https://data.stackexchange.com/hermeneutics/query/1813994/percentage-of-questions-with-at-least-one-answer-accepted-answer-per-month#graph) per month. (These two queries are taken from an answer to a question on another meta: [Is there a way to measure the effectiveness of MO?](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/2774))